# How to put an alert box using javascript and asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I just want to know how to put an alert box using javascript and asp.net. Basically I have created a webpage where the admin will fill up a form, and then after clicking the submit button, there should be an alert box that will popup with a message that says upload successful or upload failed.

I tried doing it with this code(I only included the javascript code and the asp submit button):

```
<script>
    function UploadStatusSuccessful()
    {
        alert("Upload Successful!");
    }
</script>

<script>
    function UploadStatusFail()
    {
        alert("Upload Failed!");
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="submitButton" Text="Save 
Item" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

and here is the code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        int item_brandId = 
        ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByBrand(itemBrand.Text);
        string item_model = itemModel.Text;
        double item_price = Convert.ToDouble(itemPrice.Text);
        string item_image1 = Session["PicturePath1"].ToString();
        string item_image2 = Session["PicturePath2"].ToString();
        string item_description = itemDescription.Text;
        string item_necktype = itemNeckType.Text;
        string item_body = itemBody.Text;
        string item_fretboard = itemFretboard.Text;
        string item_fret = itemFret.Text;
        string item_bridge = itemBridge.Text;
        string item_neckpickup = itemNeckPickup.Text;
        string item_bridgepickup = itemBridgePickup.Text;
        string item_hardwarecolor = itemHardwareColor.Text;

        if (itemType1.Checked)
        {
            int item_type = 
            ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByType(itemType1.Text);
            ItemType = item_type;
        }
        else if (itemType2.Checked)
        {
            int item_type = 
            ConnectionClassBrands.GetIdByType(itemType2.Text);
            ItemType = item_type;
        }

        var item = new instrumentItem
        {
            typeId = ItemType,
            brandId = item_brandId,
            model = item_model,
            price = item_price,
            itemimage1 = item_image1,
            itemimage2 = item_image2,
            description = item_description,
            necktype = item_necktype,
            body = item_body,
            fretboard = item_fretboard,
            fret = item_fret,
            bridge = item_bridge,
            neckpickup = item_neckpickup,
            bridgepickup = item_bridgepickup,
            hardwarecolor = item_hardwarecolor
        };

        ConnectionClassGuitarItems.AddStringInstrumentItems(item);

        Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "JavaScript:return 
        UploadStatusSuccessful()");

        ClearTextFields2();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "JavaScript:return 
        UploadStatusFail()");
    }


}
```

I tried doing the Button1.Attrbute.Add but no alert box is showing. Please provide solutions or actual examples on how to achieve this. Also kindly inform me if there are wrong syntax that i missed so that i can correct it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` in code behind to show alert message like below . You need to `Scriptmanager` control to your aspx page . This is the recommended way

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), 
          "err_msg", 
          "alert('Upload failed!');",
          true);
```

Otherwise you can simple do like below

`Response.Write("<script>alert('Upload failed!');</script>");`

Link for scriptmanager control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx

Comment: is it necessary to put the "err_msg" or can i just remove it?

Comment: @BoomClick this is a key used to identify your script you can put any unique value but it should not be empty

Comment: oh i see now. Its working finally. And one more thing, is it possible to edit the positioning of the alert box? because its appearing way up the webpage.

Comment: I dont think so because its just a javascript alert not a modal window. If you want to position it then you need to use `window.open` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: and show your message in an external page on modal window with position.

Comment: @BoomClick can you please mark this as answer it resolves your issue?

Comment: can you style window.open as well?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by style but yes you can do lots of re positioning and add scrollbars to window.open() check this link for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>UploadStatusSuccessful();</script>", false);
```